# how to create JIRA quick filter where assignee is Unassigned

Tags: jira

I defined a unassigned user in my JIRA account and now I can assign to unassigned user. when I want to get all those tickets using quick filter - I can't.
any solution / workaround will be most welcome.

Comment: JIRA treats an empty assignee field as 'unassigned'. You can search for it with 'assignee is empty'

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In your case, create filter and type in JQL:

```
assignee = unassigned user
```

Or if no assignee

```
assignee is empty
```

You can select the widget "filter result" to show the consequence on your dashboard.

Comment: You can of course also do a combination: `assignee = unassigned user OR assignee is EMPTY`

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion create a specific user to assign those task which you want to consider as unassigned is pointless and it would require additional effort when Jira already gives you that feature natively.

You only need to use JQL filters to query. For instance, if using 'python-jira' module you can easily do the following:

```
# Get all issues which are unassigned and belongs to project 'DESK'
issues = jira.search_issues('assignee=null and project=DESK')
print issues
```

This will output all unassigned issues (of course it will vary from your JIRA DB):

```
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'DESK-9', id=u'10009'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'DESK-7', id=u'10007'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'DESK-5', id=u'10004'>]
```